# Use option select on php MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Please help me, how to use option select to display data from database using MYSQLi .

> _________________      ______________
>   |  ALL                     |/|        |  SEARCH          |
>   | Mexico                  |        _____________
>   | France                  |
>   |_______________

When click **SEARCH** by choosing "*Mexico*" for example. The data of Mexico on the database will show.

Comment: Just send the selected option value to the PHP server. Then select the data and echo to show.

Comment: Please, how .......

Comment: You need to show some effort, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: thank you guys. Sorry I really need idea , I dont know how to explain my code anyway, but I did my best to search online the possible solutions on my problem but it always shows the input instead of option/select. I appreciate your words, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
echo ' <select onclick="getData(this.value)" name="names">';
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {

      echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" >'.$row["name"].'</option>';  

    }
echo '</select>';
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<script>
function getData(id){
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'test.php?id='+id,
     data: "json",
     success: function(response){
         alert(response);
     }
});
}

</script>
```

test.php CODE :

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

  $id=$_GET["id"];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='$id'";

    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {

      $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)
    echo json_encode($row);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you too , but it soved for you ?